# JNA CreatePseudoConsole declaration

Tags: java, winapi, jna

What is correct JNA declaration of [`CreatePseudoConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/createpseudoconsole) function?

Windows API declaration is following:

```
HRESULT WINAPI CreatePseudoConsole(
    _In_ COORD size,
    _In_ HANDLE hInput,
    _In_ HANDLE hOutput,
    _In_ DWORD dwFlags,
    _Out_ HPCON* phPC
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HRESULT is a 32-bit integer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/705fb797-2175-4a90-b5a3-3918024b10b8), so your function declaration would be `int CreatePseudoConsole()`.

As for the arguments, you can extend `Structure` to create your own [COORD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ms682119) structure, mapping the two Windows [SHORT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types#short)s to Java's 16-bit integer `short`.

JNA already has a mapping for [`WinNT.HANDLE`](https://static.javadoc.io/net.java.dev.jna/jna/5.2.0/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinNT.HANDLE.html), so just use that.  You can optionally use JNA's [`DWORD`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinDef.DWORD.html) mapping, but most of the time I just map those directly to an `int`.

So the only thing left is the pointer to `HPCON`, which is not directly mapped.  The docs describe this as a pointer to a `HANDLE`.  You can use [`HANDLEByReference`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinNT.HANDLEByReference.html) here, or extend that to your own more narrowly typed class.  This [mapping of HGLRCByReference](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/f5bdc9e3efdae3b6e9341015109e3a294332939a/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinDef.java#L1758) is a good example to use if you want to create an HPCONByReference.